# How to disable "Restored Session" message from appearing every time I run Terminal?

Tags: macos, big-sur, zsh

Every time I run terminal on macOS BigSur I see a message like this:

```
[Restored 10 Jun 2021 at 12:18:19]
Restored session: Thu Jun 10 12:18:16 WEST 2021
```

I want the sessions to be restored. I don't want to see this message thousands of times?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the second line starting ‘Restored session’ by editing `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` and removing or commenting out line 216:

> ```
> (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
> ```

I don't believe it's possible to remove the first line as that's output by the Terminal app itself.